# Why is my custom Slick slider not aligning and working properly on the website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modified Slick slider that has an overlay+text when hovering over each image. The slider, images, hover effect, etc. are working great on codepen.io but it does not work the same when I put it on the website. I am not sure why! The images should be displayed on 1 row with arrows/dots navigating to next image. And it should be resizing based on screen width (that's how its set up on codepen).

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  speed: 800,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: false,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  dots: true,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }

  ]
})
```

```css
.slide,
.sliderimg {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
}

.slick-next:before {
  content: "→";
}

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  z-index: 999;
}

.slick-next {
  right: 0 !important;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: 0 !important;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}

.slider {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin: 10px;
}

.slick-slide .sliderimg {
  width: 100%;     
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.card:hover {
  background: rgb(253, 201, 154, 0.8);
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;

}

.card-content {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
}

.card-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300; 
}

.car:hover .sliderimg {
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.card:hover .middle {
  opacity: 3; 
}
/* text on hover */
.car:hover .middle {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 47%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  left: 35%;
  visibility: visible;

}

/*dots*/
.slick-dots button {
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-size: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #e7dff4; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*border: 2px solid #AE95DA;*/
}
.slick-dots button:hover,
.slick-dots .slick-active button {
  background: #AE95DA;
  opacity: 1;

}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.8/slick-theme.min.css'>
<link rel="text/html" href="./style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" integrity="sha512-6lLUdeQ5uheMFbWm3CP271l14RsX1xtx+J5x2yeIDkkiBpeVTNhTqijME7GgRKKi6hCqovwCoBTlRBEC20M8Mg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="main">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="car">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">

          <img class="sliderimg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657720209025-e7c1319c1147?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NTg0OTg1NzQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80">
          <div id="" class="middle">
            <div class="text">Jane Smith<br/>CEO/Founder</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-title"></div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">

          <img class="sliderimg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657720209025-e7c1319c1147?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NTg0OTg1NzQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80">
          <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">Jennifer Spinner<br/>Company Director</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-title"></div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



        <div class="car">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">

          <img class="sliderimg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1657720209025-e7c1319c1147?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NTg0OTg1NzQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80" >
          <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">Samuel Stopper<br/>Finance Director</div>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-title">
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js'></script>
```

I have been trying to fix it for hours but with no success. Any help would be be greatly, greatly appreciated!! Thank you.

Comment: It seems like it works well on small screens.

Comment: Thanks. The code snippet above is not what is showing on the actual website. Even on small screens like iphone XR or iphone Pro 12 the images are stacked up, the overlay spills over the image, and the arrows/dots are not showing. I am not sure why it's not working properly

Comment: I can't tell you why it works differently on your website. I literally copy-pasted your code into a snippet (and hope I didn't fix anything by mistake), so it may behave differently due to missing resources.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you please tell me how I should be linking the resources properly to make it work on the live website? I placed the Javascript  links (i.e. all the <link rel='stylesheet' href=..." at the top) in my header.php (in <header> section), added the HTML code to my homepage.php file (the slider should be on the home page), added the JavaScript  function to my JS folder (its contained in a file called all.js) and I added the CSS code to my main CSS file on the site. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Sounds like the CSS and JS files are properly linked and loaded with the page. I'd check if the relative/absolute paths of the files are correct, and see if network tab shows any errors in the dev tools. Also, in the snippet above, I'm seeing that two jQuery versions are loaded (i.e. `3.6.0` at the top and `2.1.3` at the bottom), as well as two Slick JS and CSS versions (i.e. `1.8.1` and `1.5.9`). Even if the API remains the same and won't break the functionality, it's still a good idea to keep only one version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested your code in Xampp localhost and it works with some adjustments.
Our test: [at codepen](https://codepen.io/crux1/pen/eYjEegd)
We realigned the header info scripts so each is apparent (which is needed vs which is not needed). The following should be in header:

```
slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css
slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css
2.1.3/jquery.min.js
slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js
```

Note that we are not sure if those other header scripts might be for some other stuff on your webpage that we're not aware of (that is not shown by you in the example provided).

No lower BUTTON will show when all three images are visible.
When two images are visible TWO lower buttons will show.
When one image is visible all THREEE lower buttons will show.
I temporarily added a "1,2,3" number on the overlay to see that we are on the correct overlay image in small screens.

To fix the click arrows (in original CSS or in custom.css):
.slick-slide (margin:0px) to give the click arrows '>' full visibility on page.
Or in a custom.css overwrite original code to bump the arrows ">" in a slight bit. These arrows show up on small screens when the three images are one visible image.

```
/*--custom bump arrows--*/
.slick-prev {margin-left:20px;}
.slick-next {margin-right:20px;}
```

Here is the first part of the JS we tried. You might need to adjust it for your needed width factors:

```
<script>
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 800,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  autoplay: false,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking so much time to help me out. I am super grateful!! It seems to be working fine. I followed your instruction and implemented the code. Is there a way to make the text align to center when the screen size is reduced? When I try mobile, the text goes down to bottom-right corner. Also, I received an error message regarding slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css and slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css (Inspect tool on Microsoft Edge stated these are not executable) but the code is working fine without them (had slick.css  in my files). Thank you so much!

Comment: If that CDN is having errors might try another CDN (google etc).
Or as you did just place in subdirectory on your website.
To center the text (see updated code at our codepen).
A more ideal compact way though is via flex or flexbox (just suggesting) plus less DIV's (but that involves more time coding on your part).
Here is part of the CSS revised:  
.car:hover .middle 
  top: 45%;
  left: 30%;

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your help! Thank you so much, this change worked well. Can I possibly ask you one last question - is there a way to reduce the image size slightly on Desktop view? The images shrink seamlessly on tablet/mobile but desktop view is a bit large. Would you know the best way of doing so without impacting too much the way the slider works now? I am very sorry to bother you with so many questions! Thank you so much!

Comment: Change CSS .slider width down to perhaps 75% in CSS (or as you need). See our adjustments on our codepen example.
Altering the .slider width though yields more left-right margins, but the image is smaller overall.
KenWheelers slick slide website instruction code is setup slightly different from the way you have it, but alas.
There are plenty of other free software image sliders on the web to try, some better than others.
Note: A truly centered text is top 50%, left 50%, but we set it so as to not necessitate much further code revision on your part in that particular slider software.

Comment: Thank  you so much, its working great. I really appreciate all your time and amazing help!